# Blender exported gltf model doesn't look as it should

Tags: rendering, texturing, gltf

I followed a course and managed to create a 3D model,this is my very first attempt.I rendered the image ,it was all good.But when I tried to view it on a gltf viewer,it does not appear to be same as the rendered image.I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this,since I am a beginner,stuck up with this and not being able to figure out the issue.[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using lit materials?

Comment: glTF doesn't have the same material system as Blender.  Try setting up your materials as described in the [glTF export documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#materials).

Comment: Hi, but why doesn't blender convert its own material to gltf system automatically ? :)

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/43930 for the details — in short, many parts of Blender's material system cannot automatically be converted to glTF (or anything else).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)